# Can I put $SECONDS into an environment variable in a bash script?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, function

I'd like to be able to have `$SECONDS` shown with hours, minutes, seconds in an environment variable, so I only need to use, e.g. `$RUNTIME` in various places in the script rather than have the whole thing every time I want to use it.

I don't know what formatting to use to allow it to go into a variable:

```
export RUNTIME="$(($SECONDS / 3600))hrs $((($SECONDS / 60) % 60))min $(($SECONDS % 60))sec"
```

So I can simply:

```
echo "The script ran for: $RUNTIME"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining RUNTIME as a variable wouldn't help as it outputs a constant value, always, the run time when it was defined. Try a shell `function` in lieu:

```
runtime() { 
   printf "%dhrs %dmin %dsec\n" $((SECONDS / 3600)) \
                                $(((SECONDS / 60) % 60)) \
                                $(($SECONDS % 60)); 
}
runtime
```

and call it / use it with a "command substitution".

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. This is the first time i've had enough points to upvote the answer :) I've also added 'function' and 'bash-function' to the tags.

Comment: Note that you don't need `$` on variables in arithmetic contexts such as inside `$(( ... ))`. Also, your function only needs to be exported if it is to be used in a child `bash` shell.

Comment: And why would you `echo` it? It's a function and already prints. All you need is `RUNTIME()`. I made some changes to remove the unnecessary parts of your answer.

Comment: @terdon: Can I reject your edits, and how? a) the OP used RUNTIME in an extended `echo` b) s/he exported the variable c) the algorithm as given was used, and the `$` doesn't hurt..